# Combine 2 one-row dataframes in the same row

Tags: pandas

So I have 2 dfs with the following structure

```
   DF1: A B   DF2:  C D
        1 2         3 4
```

And I would like to combine them like this:

```
DF: A B C D
    1 2 3 4
```

But instead I get this with every function I tried (merge, join, concat):

```
DF: A  B  C  D
    1  2  NA NA
    NA NA 3  4
```

How can I merge them like I want them to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you tried `pandas.concat`?

```
import pandas as pd

out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: @richardec I think you forgot the important options :p

Comment: @Backtr4ck why don't you provide your input data as dataframe? **In particular it is important to know what the indexes are** and also provide the commands that failed for you. Check the update

Comment: oh wait. I just noticed df2 has index=1!! Let me reset that

Comment: that's why it's important to provide a full reproducible example ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.concat` with `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```